# How to create a bit array objective C

Tags: objective-c, bitarray

I want to make a bit array or bit vector of items I have in an array so that I can create a binary fingerprint to compare to an object's fingerprint.

Here is an example:

Base fingerprint...
All "available" colors

1. colorsArray[blue, red, white, green, orange];
2. Make this into a binary array (or whatever)
3. This is the result = masterPrint[1,1,1,1,1];
4. Now I have a separate object that has the colors red and blue in it (object[red,blue])
5. This object's fingerprint is object's print = [1,1,0,0,0];
6. Compare two prints, master print [1,1,1,1,1] and object print [1,1,0,0,0];
7. Result is two matches 40%

How can I accomplish this?  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Better option is **CFMutableBitVector**

**CFBitVector** and its derived mutable type, **CFMutableBitVector**, manage ordered collections of bit values, which are either `0` or `1`.

**CFBitVector** creates static bit vectors and **CFMutableBitVector** creates dynamic bit vectors.

See the class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBitVectorRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: I have read this reference but I am unsure as to how to take an array and parse it into this. Do you have any sample code? Thank you

Comment: here is the example https://github.com/llvm-mirror/lldb/blob/master/examples/summaries/cocoa/CFBitVector.py

Comment: if the answer helped you, please accept it. Do the code your own, then any issues occurred, post it as a good question. thanks

Comment: I will, I'm looking through it, it looks interesting, but there has to be an easier way, it looks like too much code just to add some values to a 1,0 array...

Comment: coding with bit arrays is little difficult always for me too :)

Comment: Depending on your application, there might be an argument for using one of the many bit-vector implementations offered by C++ - which you can easily interwork with objective-c.  Performance might be one very good reason for doing so, but an even stronger case might be the selection of high-performance algorithms you can apply to the data from the [algorithm collection](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) in STL.

Comment: Hi marko, how can I integrate the C++ bitvector in obj c?  Thanks, great answer!  If you post i'll mark it

Comment: i think, just rename your .m file to .mm .. (example:rename "view controller.m" to "view controller.mm". then it should support C++ codes